# get first row data from column from parameter tableadapter

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

I am trying to return the first row value on colunn rep-id. Here is what I have but is only working half way I am not getting my string value

```
Dim text as string = sdTableAdapter.Repds(endweek).Rows (0)
```

How do I get the first row string from my column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method, assuming it's the first column:

```
Dim table As DataTable = sdTableAdapter.Repds(endweek)
Dim text As String = table.Rows(0).Field(Of String)(0)
```

You can also use it via column-name:

```
Dim text As String  = table.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("ColumnName")
```

You'll get an exception if the type is not `String`, then you need to convert it from the correct type(e.g. `Int32`):

```
Dim text As String  = table.Rows(0).Field(Of Int32)("ColumnName").ToString()
```

Comment: thank you exactly what I needed. Sorry about the format I am writing from my phone pc is down